# Why is this IF statement not compiling

Tags: mysql

The code is below.

```
SELECT MAX(days) INTO @_days FROM my_table; -- compiles ok

-- problems start here

IF DAYOFWEEK(@_days) = 6 THEN                           
    INSERT INTO my_table(days) VALUES(DATE_ADD(@_days,INTERVAL 2 DAY));
ELSE
    INSERT INTO my_table(days) VALUES(DATE_ADD(@_days,INTERVAL 1 DAY));
END IF;
```

The error I get is #1064. My mysql version is 5.5.25

Answer (score 0):

It should work as I cant see any syntax error. Check for any special characters in your editor.

You can also try:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(days) VALUES(DATE_ADD(@_days,INTERVAL IF(DAYOFWEEK(@_days) = 6, 2, 1) DAY));
```